# How to run threads without using Runnable implementations?

Tags: java, multithreading

I found the following excerpt in a Java Textbook:

```
"I've seen examples that don't use a separate 
Runnable Implementation, but Instead Just make a 
subclass of Thread and override the Thread's runO 
method. That way,you call the Thread's no-arg 
constructor when you make the new thread; 
Thread t = new Thread(); //no Runnable"
```

Shouldn't the last line be

```
Thread t = new <Some class that extends Thread class and over rides its run method>();
```

Am I correct?

Could somebody provide sample code that illustrates the above excerpt?

Comment: Yes. You are right.. I think the *author* wants to say the same thing :)

Comment: You are correct. I have no examples to hand.

Comment: It's generally recommended to implement `Runnable` and not extend `Thread`. Implementing interfaces is always cleaner than inheriting implementations. If I had my way there'd be a school called 'Interface Oriented Programming' that tended to discourage implementation inheritance given it violates implementation hiding and abstraction. It has its uses but should only be used inside a implementation and with great caution as a way for others to extend functionality and integrate with your libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you are talking about runtime polymorphism. Yes you could do that. See following exmaple:

```
class Flight extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello World.. I took off");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flight flight = new Flight();
    Thread myflight = new Flight();//See how i used runtime polymorphism.
    flight.start();
    myflight.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

If you create an instance of `Thread` without overriding `run()` of supplying a `Runnable`, the thread would execute the default empty `run()` method.

I wonder if this quote is accurate, as it specifically mentions sub-classing Thread, but the code `Thread t = new Thread();` clearly doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `run` method "inline" with an anonymous subclass:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        doStuffInPaarralel();
    }
}.start();
```

Not that there are a lot of advantages to this over supplying a separate `Runnable` class. You rearely need a thread, that just does one thing and dies, it's kinda wasteful. A better way is to use a `ThreadPool`, which has a bunch of threads, that are available for executing any task when you need them. That way, you reduce the overhead of starting up and destroying the thread every time.